# How to write a TFS query for features thas has only resolved and closed children

Tags: tfs

I would like to identify features that is done or almost done using a query.  How do I query for features thas has only resolved and closed child items?

Answer (score 1):

You could use query condition on parent item or child item with usage of "**Tree of workitems**" query (Replace Done with resolved/closed in your scenario ):

Note that select **Match linked work items first** under Filter options.

[image]

More details please take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Use a tree query to view hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-a-tree-query-to-view-hierarchies)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried, but I soon realized that I am confined to "Work items with direct links".  This is due to the fact I am using "Query Based Boards" as native TFS Boards does not support query.  In this case, I think I could use "Only return items that do not have matching links".  I will try and update the post with the info.

Comment: Hi Kay, any update on this issue. Were you able to resolve?  Kindly share your solution here, if you already figured it out. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.